# TypeError: Timestamp subtraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a script that goes and collects data.  I am running into the `TypeError: Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones` error. I have looked at other postings on this error, but had trouble finding a solution for me.

How can I bypass this error. Once the data is collected, I don't manipulate it and I don't quite understand why I cannot save this `dataframe` into an excel document.  Can anyone offer help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import pvlib
from pvlib.forecast import GFS, NAM

#directories and filepaths
barnwell_dir = r'D:\Saurabh\Production Forecasting\Machine Learning\Sites\Barnwell'
barnwell_training = r'8760_barnwell.xlsx'

#constants
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test' + '_PythonExport.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')    
time_zone = 'Etc/GMT+5'
barnwell_list = [r'8760_barnwell.xlsx', 33.2376, -81.3510] 

def get_gfs_processed_data1():
    start = pd.Timestamp(datetime.date.today(), tz=time_zone) #used for testing last week
    end = start + pd.Timedelta(days=6)
    gfs = GFS(resolution='quarter')
    #get processed data for lat/long point
    forecasted_data = gfs.get_processed_data(barnwell_list[1], barnwell_list[2], start, end)
    forecasted_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')


get_gfs_processed_data1()
```

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: `forecasted_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')` throws the exception

Comment: If you print `start` and `end` is the tz attribute visible?

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7056 ? May be it is helpful.

Answer (score 9):

When I run your sample code I get the following warning from XlsxWriter at the end of the stacktrace:

```
"Excel doesn't support timezones in datetimes. "
TypeError: Excel doesn't support timezones in datetimes. 
Set the tzinfo in the datetime/time object to None or use the
'remove_timezone' Workbook() option
```

I think that is reasonably self-explanatory. To strip the timezones from the timestamps pass the `remove_timezone` option as recommended:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test' + '_PythonExport.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'remove_timezone': True})
```

When I make this change the sample runs and produces an xlsx file. Note, the `remove_timezone` option requires XlsxWriter >= 0.9.5.

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  I updated my `writer` variable to pass the 'remove_timezone' option, and also updated the package to 0.9.5, however I still get the same timestamp error.

Comment: If you can omit the timezone from your calculation, or adjust for it, then you won't have to use the `remove_timezone` options. Also, make sure that the result in the xlsx file with the timezone stripped meets your expectation.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately the data I pull from the `pvlib` library is tz specific. This is quite odd. I wonder if I should just create a new column and reset the `df` index to the new column. Just seems more like a patch than a solution though.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete timezone from all your `datetime` columns like that:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(['datetimetz']).columns:
    df[col] = df[col].dt.tz_convert(None)

df.to_excel('test' + '_PythonExport.xlsx')
```

after that you save excel without any problem

Note:

> To select Pandas datetimetz dtypes, use 'datetimetz' (new in 0.20.0)
>   or 'datetime64[ns, tz]'